# UICollectionView on top of UIScrollView scroll issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a custom tab bar that i've created, it has scroll view with 5-6 pages and in few of those pages I have a UITableView nor UICollectionView. My problem is when I scroll the collection view down, it works fine, but when it stops and I try to scroll to top or bottom once again, it scroll to the side with the UIScrollView, completely ignores the collection or table.

Does anyone knows this problem? Can someone help me solve it?

Thanks in advance

---

I've added a diagram that shows what I'm up to:

[image: collection view diagram]

Comment: Have you considered using a UIPageViewController instead of a UIScrollView?

Comment: Your description says you have a UICollectionView _on top of_ a UIScrollView.  Did you mean inside?

Comment: Yes, I meant inside the UIScrollView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bad things when gestures share responsive area :-)
we are clumsy creatures and most of the times even when we sure we scroll perfectly up,we are not, and usually scroll up-right or up-left.
funny though that your subview ignore the touch and the super view respond.this require some touches debugging.

there is a obvious solution, but you wont like - change the design completely to one collection with different  section for each collection.

this is not a small change and will probably require a costume layout ,  so before you do that do some touches debug and make sure no subview in your hierarchy is blocking the user interaction for some reason.